# Parse delete Object

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I want to delete my data. 
I get "Student_ID" from my column consist of the ID at Parse.
I am not sure where is the problem, the code had success one to two times when I tried, and with pressing the button multiple times. Maybe because it need to wait for the request from my database parse?
I think the problem is at the for loop, it seem to stucks there.
Can anyone fix it?

```
public void deleteStudent(){
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("Student");
    query.whereEqualTo("Student_ID",ID);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null) {


                for (ParseObject delete : parseObjects) {
                    delete.deleteInBackground();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error in deleting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm unclear what the problem is. Doesn't delete? Is `ID` always the same? If so it's not going to delete it multiple times.

Comment: It only works one to two times after I try many times. I am also not sure why. It will get the current ID of the data with is unique. If it is deleted, it will remove from parse. But it only work one-two times only.

Comment: I think I solve it !I just add [ID=student_ID.getText().toString();]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this line to the void.

ID=student_ID.getText().toString();

Answer (score 0):

parse dose have an api to bulk delete, so save a for loop

```
ParseObject.deleteAllInBackground
```